# Dynamic form with ContentChildren

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular2-forms

I am trying to create a dynamic form with ContentChildren, it is done, but I have 2 problems

1. Without Material: I can't capture the input values when submitting, I don't know how to do it
2. With Material: I can't capture the references to the inputs, adding "mat-form-field" made things complicated.

I leave an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-contentchild-directive-q9tckq) in stackblitz. Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to capture and watch for input values I would suggest you to add `ngModel` directive to all your `input` controls inside your dynamic form. This will automatically create an instance of `FormControl` for each `input` which you can add to your dynamic `FormGroup`:

> Note: you can also get input value by accessing `inputElement.value` but
> you have to listen for `input` event in order to watch for the changes

**html**

```
<filter-form (onSubmit)="onSubmit($event)">
    <input type="text" placeholder="0.00" propertyName="1" ngModel/>
    <input type="text" placeholder="0.00" propertyName="2" ngModel/>
    <input type="text" placeholder="0.00" propertyName="3" ngModel/>
    <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput type="text" placeholder="0.00" propertyName="4" ngModel/>
    </mat-form-field>
</filter-form>
```

You can grab that NgModel instance by injecting it into your custom directive:

```
@Directive({
  selector: "input"
})
export class FocusDirective {

  @Input() propertyName: string;

  constructor(public ngModel: NgModel) {}
}
```

Now, you can add FormControl instances to your formGroup:

```
ngAfterContentInit(): void {
  console.log("ngAfterContentInit::input is: ", this.items);
  this.items.toArray().forEach(x => {
    this.formGroup.addControl(
      x.propertyName,
      x.ngModel.control <--------------------------- this one
    );
  });
}
```

In order to get all `ContentChildren` regardless of the nesting level you have to use `descendants` option:

```
@ContentChildren(FocusDirective, { descendants: true }) items: QueryList<FocusDirective>;
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-contentchild-directive-ompa3n?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchild-component%2Ffield-validation.component.ts)**